# My domain forwards to www.www.www.domain.com

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04, apache2

In `ubuntu server 16.04` I have a wordpress site and I want to link it with a domain name.

I set up the DNS records in `vutlr` and then I set up also the [Virtual hosts in my server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

However, when I type www.mydomain.com, I am forwarding to www.www.www.mydomain.com

Why is this happening?

The virtual host is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin  myemail@email.com
        ServerName mydomain.com
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite-access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

my `wp-config.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * The base configuration for WordPress
 *
 * The wp-config.php creation script uses this file during the
 * installation. You don't have to use the web site, you can
 * copy this file to "wp-config.php" and fill in the values.
 *
 * This file contains the following configurations:
 *
 * * MySQL settings
 * * Secret keys
 * * Database table prefix
 * * ABSPATH
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'mydbsite');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'sadadsadsadads');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'asdadasdadasdassdadas');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');

/**#@+
 * Authentication Unique Keys and Salts.
 *
 * Change these to different unique phrases!
 * You can generate these using the {@link https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ WordPress.org secret-key service}
 * You can change these at any point in time to invalidate all existing cookies. This will force all users to have to log in again.
 *
 * @since 2.6.0

 define('AUTH_KEY',         ',<sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'Jssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ');
define('NONCE_KEY',        ':sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('AUTH_SALT',        'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
define('NONCE_SALT',       'sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');

/**#@-*/

/**
 * WordPress Database Table prefix.
 *
 * You can have multiple installations in one database if you give each
 * a unique prefix. Only numbers, letters, and underscores please!
 */
$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.



define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

There is also an htcaccess file inside the folder of the wordpess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mysite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also the error log from apache2

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitIn$

Finally the settings in the DNS records in vultr

[image]

Comment: Check your home and siteurl in Settings - General.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton ! Indeed, there were the old urls. I updated them and now  I remain in the www.mydomain.com . However, now the internal pages don't work...

Comment: In fact,now all the internal pages redirect to www.www.... for example I click www.mydomain.com/contact and i go to www.www.mydomain.com/contact

Comment: @MichaelHampton please post your comment as an answerto get the credits.. thanks again for your help

Comment: It sounds like you just need to clear your browser cache now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have wasted over 3 hours, trying to understand why a simple procedure (I have done it many times) wasn't working...

However, the solution was very simple...

1. I changed the home and siteurl in Settings - General in order to have the domain name. (Thanks to  @Michael Hampton comment!)
2. **Then I simply cleared the cache in my browser and all worked**

...